# How to execute a single subtest from OpenSSL 80-test_ssl_new.t?

Tags: unit-testing, openssl

I compiled OpenSSL 1.1.1k and one subtest in 80-test_ssl_new.t is failing. How to debug this? The test is a test suite consisting out of 29 sub tests. Only sub test 20 is failing: 20-cert-select. Can I somehow run only this specific sub test?

Just running 80-test_ssl_new.t works like this:

```
HARNESS_VERBOSE=yes make TESTS="test_ssl_new" test
```

which already generates quite a lot of output and runs all 29 sub tests.

BR, Rene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are instructions here:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/test/README.ssltest.md

See the section at the end "Running a test manually"

Comment: Helpful. I was hoping to be able to run a single iteration for a single sub test. But just running a sub test already helped quite a lot. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/test/README.ssltest.md#running-a-test-manually

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative (better in my opinion) way to select a single or a few tests to run is to use the Automake-style TESTS Make variable:

```
make test TESTS=test_ssl_new
```

There's an OpenSSL-specific test runner (a Perl script) named `run_tests.pl` which selects the test based on a regexp pattern, so you shouldn't put the whole file name of the test there, nor its `.t` file extension.